# Python application architecture

Tags: python, oop, architecture

I'm trying to create task management system. (an app where somebody can create a task and set up a deadline date and get notifications). At first i will create console app and then web using django.

I already created a database.(sqlite)

I don't know how my entities are going to communicate.

First one approach:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self):
    self.UserID
    self.UserName
    self.PassHash
    # salt, Full name and etc.


class Task():
    def __init__(self):
    self.TaskID
    self.UserID 
    self.Name
    #smth subtasks, date and etc.


 class UserService():
    def __init__(UserID, TaskID):
        User = db.GetById(UserID)
        TasksList = db.GetUserTasks(UserID)

    def addTask():
        ..

    def removeTask():
        ..

    def ChangePassword():
        ..

    def ChangeUserName():
        ..
```

The last one class will contains all business logic and communication between Tasks and User classes. First ones - pure classes without any methods.

Another one approach:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self):
    self.UserID # 
    self.UserName
    self.PassHash # 3 fields will be set up by db. The last one - on #runtime
    self.TasksList = None

    def ChangePassword():
        ..

    def GetTasks():
        TaskList = db.GetUserTasks(UserID)

class Task()
    def __init__(self):
    self.TaskID
    self.UserID 
    self.Name
    self.SubTask 
    #smth else

    def AddSubTask():
          ..
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes should define objects of which you can have one or more instances of. That is for example users or tasks. **I do not think that classes in object programming are supposed to encompass raw functionality**, for that you just use functions...

With that in mind I would go with the **first approach**.

> Classes should be *classes* and functions should be *functions*  - Me

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first option because it's more readable and the structure is clearer.